# Infinity stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, higher-category-theory

I was going through some notions of stacks and higher stacks on nLab. $\infty$-stacks are usually $(\infty,1)$-sheaves which take values in $\infty$-groupoids. Now to recall, $(\infty,1)$-sheaf is a presheaf satisfying descent condition and presheaf is a functor from the $(\infty,1)$-site $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ (category equipped with coverage) to $\infty-\mathcal{Groupoid}$ ($(\infty,1)$-category made out of $\infty$-groupoids). This is the usual derived stack where the domain and co-domain are categorized. But, I have seen other examples of $\infty$-stacks where only the co-domain has been categorized but the site remains ordinary 1-site. For example, smooth $\infty$-stacks are $\infty$-stacks over 1-site $\mathcal{Diff}$ of smooth manifolds, Lie $\infty$-groupoids taking values in $\mathcal{CartSp}_{smooth}$. Also for $(\infty,2)$-sheaves / $(\infty,2)$-stacks (this might be the quasi-coherent stacks taking values in $(\infty,1)$-category), it says that it is a $(\infty,1)$-functor from the $(\infty,1)$-site $\mathcal{C}^{op}$ to $(\infty,2)$-category $(\infty,1)-\mathcal{Cat}$.

This seems a bit confusing to me. If stacks are to be defined as presheaves, they must be functors where both the co-domain and domain should be of 'equal' higher categorical values $(n,r)$. But clearly, that's not true as I see it. Is this true only for the derived stacks taking values in $\infty$-groupoids and not for all of them? Even an ordinary stack can be defined over a 1-site / $(2,1)$-site / $(2,2)$-site I guess [if it's $(2,1)$-sheaf I believe that only the $(2,1)$-site is useful as it takes values in 1-groupoids; if it takes values in 1-categories, then $(2,2)$-site might be useful]. Can you briefly clarify this point for more general higher stacks?

I have just completed my undergrad in physics, so I might not be very familiar with advanced mathematical stuff yet; I am trying to learn these things on my own. Also, this is my first time asking a question on an online platform, apologies if the question is very trivial.

Thanks.

Comment: Any (n,r)-category can be considered to be an (n',r')-category for any $n' \geqslant n$ and $r'\geqslant r$, depending on the definition of $(n,r)$-category this is either obvious or a more subtle construction. In general, functors from an $(n,r)$-category to an $(n',r')$-category without any condition on $n,r,n',r'$ form an $(n',r')$-category.  Because of this (and other reasons), it is generally much more interesting to look at functors from an (n,r)-category to an (n',r')-category when $n \leqslant n'$ and $r \leqslant r'$ but the other way is technically possible.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: NLab states there can be notions of infinity stacks taking values in (n,r) categories, though I thought for infinity stacks, the co-domain must be an infinity category; be it infinity groupoid or (infinity,1) or (infinity,n) whatever.